# export bone constraints

Tags: constraints

Good day. In Maya fbx exported there is function export constraint so I can use them in Unity, When I export armature with contraint from Blender they don't export and I don't see any option on how to do it. What are my options to export bone constraints(maybe addon exists for such purpose)?

[image]